# NSCursor reset to arrowCursor when zooming in full screen NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nscursor

I try to change cursor when scroll is zooming.

```
- (void)resetCursorRects 
{
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self addCursorRect:self.bounds cursor:[NSCursor openHandCursor]];
}
```

It works normally until I change to fullScreen mode. When I'm pinning cursor change to arrow type.

I want it working like Photos application (when zooming in the photo in fullScreen mode).